# Remote mysql not executing query: how to make it simpler?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

The query listed below is running fine on localhost but it's somehow hanging when executed remotely targeting my service provider database (both the PHP script and the SQL query in the phpMyAdmin console hang), although every chunk is returning the expected table when run individually.

What's wrong? Any suggestions on how to make it shorter or simpler and thus help the remote MySQL?

```sql
SELECT * FROM `Table1` 
WHERE `Tag1` IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT `Tag1` FROM `Table2` 
    WHERE `Tag1` NOT IN (
        SELECT `Tag1` FROM `Table2` WHERE `Tag2` = '$keyWord'
    )
)
```

Comment: Its doing a the subquery on table2 for each record in table1, try selecting tag1 first, then simply change the where to "where tag1 <> tag1_from_previous_query"

Comment: I don't see how this is using sql server, maybe you should remove the tag

Comment: Are you sure it's hanging? (Or perhaps just no rows returned...?)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @dbinns66. I'm kindly asking you to rephrase so to better understand your suggestion.

Comment: Regarding the hanging problem (thanks @jarlh for your comment), localhost takes half a second whatever the answer (on a 20MB database), whereas the remote server was not returning anything after half an hour and all watches were not displaying on my webpage... sigh!

Comment: Hi there! The problem was on the database service provider side. I don't know what they did, but after alerting them they solved it and the query runs ok now.